# Isolating Div with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running into a spot of both with trying to target elements within a div.

I have a list of items on a page and I want to be able to show a description `<div class="meta-description">` when the title (h4 / a) is hovered.

I can get this to work so that all h4 hovers show all descriptions, but I would like to be able to isolate it to the individual items within a div `<div class="content-meta">`.

Appreciate one option would be to set individual IDs for each, but this is for a template, so would rather avoid if possible.

Any guidance most appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using selector for indicating the element. There are many [traversing method](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), such as

- [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- and many others...

Try to use them in your case.